# Bintray, JCenter, Maven, MavenCentral, OSSRH, Sonatype, Nexus, how are they all related?

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype, bintray, jcenter

I have a library shared in JCenter, which I post to through Bintray.

Recently, it is announced JCenter and Bintray are sunsetting, and many advised us to go to MavenCentral. I'm looking to move migrate it over.

Then I notice within the Bintray, it is stated my library is on Maven too, and the user can get my library using

```
maven {
    url  "https://dl.bintray.com/elye-project/maven"
}
```

So I'm confused, does that means I am already in Maven? Is this is just another name for JCenter and will not be available as well?

As I read more, I found [an article](https://proandroiddev.com/publishing-a-maven-artifact-2-3-jcenter-or-mavencentral-e0f82ba3f473) stating we can publish our library from Bintray to MavenCentral too.

I also read if I need to submit my library to MavenCentral, I need to first create an issue in [Sonatype](https://issues.sonatype.org/).

Then I saw Sonatype is actually having [Nexus Repository Manager](https://oss.sonatype.org/#welcome). Then I find [OSSRH](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-guide/) uses Nexus Repository Manager.

I am super confused about what these terms are, and how are they related?

Bintray, JCenter, Maven, MavenCentral, OSSRH, Sonatype, Nexus.

Can someone give a brief description about them, and help to connect the dot for me?

Answer (score 3):

MavenCentral is the place where Java open source artifacts should be published

JCenter was such a place.

Maven is a build system, not a repository. Many repositories have Maven format, which makes them readable from Maven and Gradle.

Sonatype Nexus and JFrog Artifactory are repository managers. You can install them to manage internal and external artifacts on your own server, which is advisable inside a company.